# How to optimize a function with an inequality constraint using calculus?

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

In order to minimize a function, $f(x)$ with an equality constraint, $g(x) = 0$, we can minimize the Lagrange function $L(x, \lambda) = f(x) - \lambda g(x)$.

However, I want to minimize a function, $f(x)$, with an inequality constraint, $x \le 0$.

I think that I could approximate this by optimizing $J(x; \alpha) = f(x) + e^{\alpha x}$ for some huge number $\alpha$ because $$\lim_{\alpha\to\infty} e^{\alpha x} = \begin{cases} 0 & x < 0 \\ \infty & x > 0 \end{cases}$$

Which would make my objective function $J$ really high if I chose any positive $x$ values, and really low for negative values.

Would this work?

Comment: Do you mean for the inequalities to be strict? If not, are you familiar with Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions?

Comment: If you mean for the inequality to be strict, then your feasible region won't be closed (unless you have some other constraints dominating the inequality constraint). This leads to problems where the solution doesn't even exist. The simple canonical example is $$\min_x\{x^2:x>0\}.$$

Comment: @David The inequality for $x < 0$ should not be strict in my case--having $x = 0$ is actually fine. I am not familiar with Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions.

Comment: The KKT conditions extend the idea of Lagrange multipliers to allow for inequality constraints. They are the basis of most nonlinear optimization algorithms (which are typically methods for solving the resulting system of equations numerically). See:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could point you in the right direction.